# Compare images in gerrit

Tags: diff, gerrit

For binary files, [gerrit](/questions/tagged/gerrit) only shows some very short meta information in the diff. In the case of image files, I really would like to visually compare the old and new version. Is this possible somehow (directly with gerrit)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, yes, this has been possible since 2009 via the [`mimetype.*.safe` configuration](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#mimetype).  The review was available in version 2.0.17 and [merged](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/10275) into the codebase on July 15, 2009.  The original feature request describing this and the fix is [issue #179](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=179).

Comment: This indeed works although the Gerrit documentation's "rather than being wrapped up inside of zipped archives" sounds as if this setting would only apply to downloading files by clicking on the small icon in the patch set's header.